# Generate all binary strings of length n

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $n = 3;
    $x = array();
    function Try1($i){
        foreach(array(0,1) as $j){
            $x[$i] = $j;
            if($i==$n-1){
                print_r($x);
            }else{
                Try1($i+1);
            }
        }
    }

    Try1(0);
?>
```

I wrote a piece of code above, but when I ran I got an error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in BinaryStrings.php on line 5.

I wrote a similar version in python and it work, can you help me? Thank you ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `$x` and `$n` are not in the same scope as the rest of your code. They're defined outside the function and not passed into it, so they don't exist inside the function. `$n-1` inside the function hence equals `-1` and your code will run into an endless loop. That's why you a) turn on error reporting and b) use conditions with `<` or `>`, not `==`.

Comment: thank you very much, I change to `function Try1($i,$x,$n)` and it works very well. But how can I change $x and $n to global scope :-?

Comment: You don't. Really, you don't. (You can search for how to do it, but you really shouldn't.)

Comment: sorry, I'm embarrassed now :(

Comment: Hehe, don't take that advise too religiously, but using global variables is a bad habit to get into. Try to code your algorithm in a way that doesn't need them. :)